# AIP Sensitivity Labels added via Power Automate

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate, microsoft365, azure-information-protection

I am interested to know if its possible to apply a sensitivity label to a document received via an email and then save the document to a specific directory in one drive.

For example, lets say company xyz sends a mail with files attached that we must process, I would like the files to be removed from the mail, marked with a custom sensitivity label like xzy_secret and then store the file in a OneDrive folder called xyz_company

So all the files in that folder eventually are labelled as per the customer.

Does anyone know if this is possible? The idea is that we can then apply DLP to our customers files and ensure we can track them within the business.

Anyone have any ideas? Is there an API for doing this or a power automate method?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Send an email action (with power automate) does not support applying the sensitivity label to the email currently. Being said that, you may need to implement your needs through the Rest API, please check this article and see if it helps:

https://joannecklein.com/2019/05/06/setting-a-retention-label-in-sharepoint-from-microsoft-flow/

Comment: That's for retention labels I think. But thanks for the reply.